# is there a better way than replace to write this function?

Tags: python, homework

I am doing my homework and i have done this? Is there any other better way to do this?

```
def write_log(name, total):
    # change user input with shape names
    name = name.replace('1', 'triangle')
    name = name.replace('2', 'square')
    name = name.replace('3', 'rectangle')
    name = name.replace('4', 'pentagon')
    name = name.replace('5', 'hexagon')
    name = name.replace('6', 'octagon')
    name = name.replace('7', 'circle')

    total = int(total)

    logfile = open("text.txt", "a")

    if (total == 1):
       towrite = ('%i %s \n'
                  % (total, name))

    elif (total >= 2 and total <= 5):
       name += 's' # add s to name to make it plural
       towrite = ('%i %s \n'
                  % (total, name))
    else:
       towrite = ''
    try:
       logfile.write(towrite)
    finally:
       logfile.close()
    return
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd find it a bit more elegant to use a list of tuples:

```
replacements = [('1', 'triangle'),
                ('2', 'square'),
                # etc.
               ]

for old, new in replacements:
    name = name.replace(old, new)
```

This way, you can more easily change the code later on; e.g., when you decide you want to use `re.sub` instead of `.replace`.

Also, I'd use the [`with` statement](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) for the logfile:

```
with open("text.txt", "a") as logfile:
    # write stuff
```

This saves you the trouble of closing the file explicitly, so you can remove the exception-handling logic.

Comment: Use [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) to build the dictionary as I show in [my answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/7873/9370). Then just access the dictionary using the number as the key. +1 for using `with`.

Answer (score 7):

**-- One --**

You can use a dictionary to hold your translation data:

```
mydict = {'1':'triangle', '2':'square', '3':'rectangle',
          '4':'pentagon','5':'hexagon', '6':'octagon','7':'circle'}
```

Now your list of replacement lines becomes simply:

```
for key, value in mydict.iteritems():
    name = name.replace(key, value)
```

another option would be:

```
for key in mydict:
    name = name.replace(key, mydict[key])
```

To make this part complete, consider also a tuple for holding your data as indicated in @larmans answer. See also comments in the answers. I think there are interesting hints about which could be the best alternative for different cases.

**-- Two --**

also remember you can do

```
2 <= total <= 5
```

instead of

```
total >= 2 and total <= 5
```

**-- Three --**

Note you dont need parenthesis in the `if` expressions. Just do this:

```
if total == 1:
```

Comment: No need for a `dict`, since there's no lookup going on. A list of tuples would suffice.

Comment: But better create the dict like this: `mydict = {'1':'triangle', '2':square ... }`

Comment: And who said a "list of tuples"  is better than a dict for anything? A dict is simpler to input and lighter on the system. No need for a listof tuples in there.

Comment: This doesn't work as written.  The `mydict=` line is a syntax error, and iterating over mydict (if it were a dict) gives the keys, not (key, value) pairs.

Comment: @larsman, use of a dict for lookup is a very common strategy. I'm not sure if a tuple is a bit more light or a bit more faster, but I think a dict is a good thing to show for a homework. He want to translate numbers into figures, so lets provide him with a dictionary !

Comment: @DSM already seen, corrected

Comment: @leo thanks, some link about why this is better ?

Comment: @joaquin I don't have a link, but I find it better more because it's just shorter. :) (but of course you can also use your method instead)

Comment: @joaquin: my point is that the `dict` is *not* used for lookup, just iteration. There's a syntax error in your example, btw.

Comment: @leo, No, you were right, it was an error I always, **always** fall in. You can not do `dict('1'='b')` It produces `SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression` (you can do `dict(b='1')` though)

Comment: @jsbueno: `dict` is not "lighter on the system". Iterating over a list is faster than iterating over a `dict`.

Comment: Use [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) to build the dictionary as I show in [my answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/7873/9370).There is no need to iterate over the dictionary; once you have the dictionary you can just access the dictionary using the number as the key.

Answer (score 3):

Below I've answered the question about a better way to write the replacement, but I've also re-written your code in some other ways that I will explain below how and why I changed it the way I did.

Starting with `def write_log(name, total):` it would be better to use a more meaningful variable name, `num`, since you expect a number which you'll later be converting into a `name`.

It is good that you used `total = int(total)` to make sure that the input is, indeed, a number. We'll do that with the new variable `num`, as well. Note, that if this fails it will throw a `ValueError` exception.

Next, since you have a list of names, make them explicitly a list with `['triangle','square'...]`. Here I also give it a meaningful variable name, `shapes`.

For the replacements, this is a good candidate for using a [`dict`ionary data structure](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). And since you want to number each of these names in order you can use the [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) function; note that by default it will start the numbering from 0, but since you want to start from 1 in your example, I added the starting number as the second argument to [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate).

Once you have enumerated your shapes list into a dictionary you can now use `num` as a key to get the value (the shape name). I wrapped it in a `try ... except` block in case someone called `write_log` with an invalid value. If an exception happens, then we print an error to `stderr` and then `return` from the function. I used this exception handling as an example to show when you would want to use `return`; in this case we are returning from the middle of the function. Note that I removed the return at the *end* of your program because you don't have to explicitly write `return` at the end unless you are actually returning some value, but in your example your function returns nothing at the end, so there is no need to write it out explicitly there at the end.

For pluralization we can simplify further by separating out the pluralization from the log message itself. We only append an `'s'` if `total` is greater than 1; I'm not sure when you had `total <= 5`, but if you really only wanted pluralization for `>=2 and <=5`, then you could write it that way, but `>1` seems to make more sense here. Then building the string for the log message is the same whether or not name is plural.

To open the log file it is better to use the [`with`](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) statement. That will put a `try ... finally` block around the code so that the file is automatically closed once the logfile variable is no longer in scope (including if an exception is thrown). What you wrote here is definitely correct (and good practice), but since it is such a common pattern the `with` statement was created for exactly this purpose (see [PEP 343](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/)).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

def write_log(num, total):
    # ensure that inputs are numbers
    num = int(num)
    total = int(total)

    shapes = ['triangle', 'square', 'rectangle', 'pentagon', 'hexagon', 'octagon', 'circle']
    replacements = dict(enumerate(shapes, 1))
    try:
        name = replacements[num]
    except KeyError:
        sys.stderr.write('Error: %i is not a valid input.\n' % (num))
        return

    if total > 1:
        name += 's' # add s to name to make it plural

    with open('text.txt', 'a') as logfile:
        msg = '%i %s \n' % (total, name)
        logfile.write(msg)

def main():
    write_log(1, 2)
    write_log(23, 5) # this will generate an error
    write_log(3, 4)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want something a bit fancy you can use `re.sub`:

```
import re
SHAPES = {
    '1': 'triangle',
    '2': 'square',
    '3': 'rectangle',
    '4': 'pentagon',
    '5': 'hexagon',
    '6': 'octagon',
    '7': 'circle',
}

name = re.sub('[1-7]', lambda m: SHAPES[m.group(0)], name)
```

Also for the output probably use a single test and format:

```
if 1 <= total <= 5:
    towrite = ('%i %s%s \n' % (total, name, "s" if name > 1 else ""))
```

Note that Python lets you run similar conditions together so you don't need to use `and` for this sort of condition.

Comment: @Duncan Use [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) to build the dictionary as I show in [my answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/7873/9370). Also, once you have the dictionary, there is no need to use `re` when you can just access the dictionary using the number as the key.

Comment: @aculich, using `re.sub` means a single pass through the string so it scales much better than lots of repeated `replace` calls. That isn't important here, but it can be significant in other similar situations.

Comment: @Duncan I would consider that to be premature optimization and harder to maintain in a way that will lead to bugs. For example, if they added three more shapes, so the total was 10, then your code would produce the incorrect result: `triangle0`. And even if you correct the regular expression in `re.sub()`, it is still worth using `dict(enumerate())` on the list to make the code easier to maintain, for example if they wanted to start the numbering from 0 or to re-order items in the list.

Comment: @aculich hence the 'If you want something a bit fancy'. I wasn't proposing it as better than the accepted solution for this case but as an alternative technique that is worth knowing. I'm agnostic about `enumerate` here: you have to either convert the matching groups to `int` or `str` the keys so it adds complexity. Also say it was mapping error numbers to messages then quite likely the numbers would soon cease being consecutive and you *have* to go back to the literal dictionary. As for the regex going wrong: `\d+` and using `SHAPES.get(m.group(0), m.group(0))` sorts that one.

Comment: @Duncan I don't understand what "fancy" means. I take it to mean "over-complicated". `int()` will do a better job of parsing the value into a list index than `re.sub()` which will raise `TypeError: expected string or buffer` if the argument passed in is already an `int`, whereas `int()` will do the correct thing whether the value is an `int` or a `string`. Since the numbering starts at 1, pad the array like this: `SHAPES = ['not a shape', 'triangle', ... ]` and then the code simplifies to `name = SHAPES[int(name)]`. Padding is not ideal, but it is a more readable declarative approach.